# Como cambiar de valor a la respuesta de jqueryuiautocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Cambiar de números a letras

```
$('#obra').autocomplete({ source: "obra_aporte", select: function(event, ui) { 
    $('[name="obra"]').val(ui.item.label); 
    $('[name="datosanio"]').val(ui.item.datosanio); 
    $('[name="datosmes"]').val(ui.item.datosmes); }
});
```

`val(ui.item.datosmes)` me da resultado ejemplo un numero 2 quiero que cambie a letras

```
2=FEBRERO
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un `switch` ya que son los meses del año.

```
var mes;
switch(ui.item.datomes){
    case "1":
        mes="ENERO"
    break;
    case "2":
        mes="FEBRERO"
    break;
     .
     .
     .
}
$('[name="datosmes"]').val(mes);
```